# While appending to an NSString object, why does my program crash after 3 appends? 

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

Here's the code

In the .h...

```
@interface Calculator2ViewController : UIViewController {

    NSString *currentNumber;
    bool buildingNumber;
    NSMutableArray *arrayExpression;
    IBOutlet UILabel *display;

}
```

In the .m...

```
-(NSString *) makeCurrentNumber{

    if(!currentNumber){
        currentNumber = [[NSString alloc] init];
        currentNumber = @"";
    }
    NSLog(@"Inside make makeCurrentNumber. The currentNumber is %@",currentNumber);
    return currentNumber;
}



-(IBAction) digitPressed:    (UIButton *)sender{

    NSString *digit = sender.titleLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"The digit is: %@", digit);
    if(!currentNumber)
      currentNumber = @"";
     currentNumber = [currentNumber stringByAppendingString:digit];
        NSLog (@"The string is: %@",currentNumber);
    buildingNumber = YES;
    }//end of digitPressed
```

**Why does my program crash after 3 appends?**

Comment: sorry, i meant my program crashes after trying to append a string three times. I was wondering what the error is in my code. Thanks

Comment: Just post code without an understandable question will not make people want to answer your question. Here at SatckOverflow we like to see some effort in the questions, what have you tried.

Comment: @Dan welcome to StackOverflow. I took the freedom to reformat and change your question a bit. To enhance the chances of getting a helpful answer, I would recommend to tell exactly what is crashing (which line, what is the debugger telling you). Is it a SIGABORT, etc...

Comment: I'm trying to make a number by using the titles of the some buttons. Every time I press a button, I would like that title to be appended to the string, currentNumber.  I've modified the code many times, this is just the latest edition.

Comment: Thanks Till, I just checked and it seems to crash at the end of 'digitPressed' because the last nslog message in the method shows up in the debugger console. When the program does crash, I don't get any special messages or anything.

Comment: are you using ARC? You should use NSMutableString instead of NSString for currentNumber variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currentNumber initially is retained by the alloc-init in makeCurrentNumber. Later on, you are replacing its value with a auto retained value (the result from `stringByAppendingString`. Enhance that line with a retain and you might get better results.

```
[...]
if(!currentNumber)
{
    [self makeCurrentNumber];
}
currentNumber = [[currentNumber stringByAppendingString:digit] retain];
NSLog (@"The string is: %@",currentNumber);
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you Till! It works perfectly and your answer makes perfect sense. Now I can continue =)

Comment: Glad i could help. Please accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark close to it.